# Save and edit Odoo.conf file in windows

Tags: configuration, odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to edit configuration file of Odoo. When I try to save it it gives me an error that I dont have access to save it. Can someone tell how to edit and save it

Answer (score 1):

Just open bloc note. With administration rights

```
 Right click on mouse execute as administrator open the file edit then save it.
```